# Is norm or seminorm countably additive?

Tags: normed-spaces

The question struck me while going through one paper which mentions Zabreiko lemma which says 'Every countably subadditive seminorm on a Banach space is continuous.' Where seminorm $p$ is said to be countably additive when $p(\displaystyle \sum_n z_n) \leq \displaystyle \sum_n p(z_n)$.

This means there do exists some seminorms which are not countably subadditive. I am struck at this point. Am I thinking something mad here. I searched on internet about countable subadditivity property of norm or seminorm. But couldn't find any relevant results. I feel triangle inequality should imply this property for both but then the statement in lemma should have been for every seminorm which is not. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Every continuous seminorm is countably subadditive. For we have
$$p\biggl(\sum_n z_n\biggr) = \lim_{k \to \infty} p\biggl(\sum_{n \leqslant k} z_n\biggr) \leqslant \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n \leqslant k} p(z_n) = \sum_n p(z_n)$$
by continuity, the triangle inequality, and the definition of the sum of an infinite series.

But discontinuous seminorms exist, and those need not be countably subadditive (unless one rejects enough of the axiom of choice, there are for example discontinuous seminorms on every infinite-dimensional Banach space). Consider on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ a discontinuous linear functional $f$ such that $f(e_n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but
$$f\biggl(\sum_n \frac{1}{n} e_n\biggr) \neq 0\,.$$
Then $\lvert f\rvert$ is a seminorm, but by construction it is not countably subadditive.

Comment: I studied your answer. I have few queries. (1) I came to read the term 'continuous seminorm' for the first time today. Is the definition for continuity of seminorm is same as that for norm ? ( I guess yes, as you have used sequential continuity in first argument). (2) Can you please explain signifance of AC in your second paragraph.

Comment: (1) It's the same definition of continuity as for all maps between topological spaces. For $\sum_n z_n$ to make sense, we need a topology on the vector space (for the conclusion here, that need not even be a vector space topology). Since we're only considering the sequence of partial sums of a series, indeed the weaker [for general spaces] assumption of sequential continuity would suffice.

Comment: (2) Technically, we can show that _some_ discontinuous seminorms exist also without choice. So I should (and will) edit that remark. But without choice, things can be very weird. To prove the existence of a discontinuous seminorm on every infinite-dimensional Banach space, one needs some choice (I don't know how much, I'm not a set-theorist).